# Elasticsearch: wildcard in query differences : "Alex*" vs "*lex*"

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I have a bunch of data indexed using keyword tokenizer.

```
{
    state: open
    settings: {
        index.number_of_replicas: 0
        index.analysis.analyzer.default.type: keyword
        index.number_of_shards: 5
        index.version.created: 900599
    }
    mappings: {
        evenements: {
            properties: {
                prenom: {
                    type: string
                }
                nom: {
                    type: string
                }
                statut: {
                    type: string
                }
                fieldDate: {
                    format: dateOptionalTime
                    type: date
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When querying

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "evenements.prenom",
            "query": "*lex*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get results, but when querying

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "evenements.prenom",
            "query": "Alex*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get no results (A ou a instead of first * does not change anything).

Any explanation about this ?

Thanks.
Yann

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set `lowercase_expanded_terms` property of query string to false. By default this property is set to true and can cause the behaviour you are having.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "lowercase_expanded_terms": false,
            "default_field": "evenements.prenom",
            "query": "Alex*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```